# Pong - Ball Resizes and Contorts Without Any Code For It

Tags: python, kivy, pong

I've been following this tutorial: http://kivy.org/docs/tutorials/pong.html.

When I copy and run the code in the section "Add Ball Animation", the ball does move around and bounce, but it's really strange. The ball periodically changes size while appearing to rotate horizontally, and then vertically. The ball usually moves pretty far off the screen when moving towards the top and right before bouncing back, I need a way to make it bounce of the sides and not bounce a bit after it reaches them. I'm pretty sure I know what part of the code I need to change() for this to happen, but I have no idea why the ball is contorting. The code is below.

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty,\
 ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint

class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(4, 0).rotate(randint(0, 360))

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.move()

     # Bounce off top and bottom
    if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top >= self.height):
        self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

    # Bounce off left and right
    if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right >= self.width):
        self.ball.velocity_x *= -1

class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos



class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

pong.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0.9

<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.pos

<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
```

Thanks for reading this.

EDIT: I just realized that the reason that the ball isn't bouncing off the right and top correctly is probably because it's contorting around constantly. I'm still not sure what causes the contortions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the size of the ball to be its position. In pong.kv

```
<PongBall>:
size: 50, 50
canvas:
    Ellipse:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.pos
```

should be

```
<PongBall>:
size: 50, 50
canvas:
    Ellipse:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
```